# Replacing different string with different new string that follows a pattern

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, vim, latex

I have

```
\title{A64L(3)}
somethings
\textbf{a64l}()
\title{MALLOC(3)}
somethings
\textbf{malloc}()
```

I want

```
\title{\hypertarget{a64l}{A64L(3)}}
somethings
\textbf{\hyperlink{a64l}{a64l}}()
\title{\hypertarget{malloc}{MALLOC(3)}}
somethings
\textbf{\hyperlink{malloc}{malloc}}()
```

or

```
\title{\hypertarget{a64l}{A64L}(3)}
somethings
\textbf{\hyperlink{a64l}{a64l}}()
\title{\hypertarget{malloc}{MALLOC}(3)}
somethings
\textbf{\hyperlink{malloc}{malloc}}()
```

These are sample file. There may anything instead of `A64L` and `MALLOC`, but follow the pattern(e.g `\title{new_word}`).

I have to do this for getting the features described https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/407884/how-to-make-a-title-as-link-target
I prefer `vim`,`sed`, `awk`.

Your answer should works for following also-

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}
\usepackage{fixltx2e} % provides \textsubscript
% use upquote if available, for straight quotes in verbatim environments
\IfFileExists{upquote.sty}{\usepackage{upquote}}{}
\ifnum 0\ifxetex 1\fi\ifluatex 1\fi=0 % if pdftex
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\else % if luatex or xelatex
  \ifxetex
    \usepackage{mathspec}
    \usepackage{xltxtra,xunicode}
  \else
    \usepackage{fontspec}
  \fi
  \defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text,Scale=MatchLowercase}
  \newcommand{\euro}{€}
\fi
% use microtype if available
\IfFileExists{microtype.sty}{\usepackage{microtype}}{}
\usepackage{longtable,booktabs}
\ifxetex
  \usepackage[setpagesize=false, % page size defined by xetex
              unicode=false, % unicode breaks when used with xetex
              xetex]{hyperref}
\else
  \usepackage[unicode=true]{hyperref}
\fi
\hypersetup{breaklinks=true,
            bookmarks=true,
            pdfauthor={},
            pdftitle={A64L(3)},
            colorlinks=true,
            citecolor=blue,
            urlcolor=blue,
            linkcolor=magenta,
            pdfborder={0 0 0}}
\urlstyle{same}  % don't use monospace font for urls
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{6pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{3em}  % prevent overfull lines
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\usepackage{pagecolor}

% Set background colour (of the page)
\definecolor{weirdbgcolor}{HTML}{FCF4F0}
\pagecolor{weirdbgcolor}

% Make bold text appear in a particular colour
\definecolor{boldcolor}{HTML}{6E0002}
\let\realtextbf=\textbf
\renewcommand{\textbf}[1]{\textcolor{boldcolor}{\realtextbf{#1}}}

% Use underlines instead of emphasis (ugh)
\renewcommand{\emph}[1]{\underline{#1}}
\hypersetup{breaklinks=false}

% % Use fixed-width font by default
% \renewcommand*\familydefault{\ttdefault}

\title{A64L(3)}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{longtable}[c]{@{}lll@{}}
\toprule\addlinespace
A64L(3) & Linux Programmer's Manual & A64L(3)
\\\addlinespace
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}

\hyperdef{}{NAME}{\section{\hyperref[NAME]{NAME}}\label{NAME}}

a64l, l64a - convert between long and base-64

\hyperdef{}{SYNOPSIS}{\section{\hyperref[SYNOPSIS]{SYNOPSIS}}\label{SYNOPSIS}}

\textbf{\#include \textless{}stdlib.h\textgreater{}}

~

\textbf{long a64l(char *}\emph{str64}\textbf{);}

~

\textbf{char *l64a(long}\emph{value}\textbf{);}

~

Feature Test Macro Requirements for glibc (see
\textbf{feature\_test\_macros}(7)): \\

~

\textbf{a64l}(), \textbf{l64a}():

~

\_SVID\_SOURCE \textbar{}\textbar{} \_XOPEN\_SOURCE~\textgreater{}=~500
\textbar{}\textbar{} \_XOPEN\_SOURCE~\&\&~\_XOPEN\_SOURCE\_EXTENDED

\hyperdef{}{DESCRIPTION}{\section{\hyperref[DESCRIPTION]{DESCRIPTION}}\label{DESCRIPTION}}

These functions provide a conversion between 32-bit long integers and
little-endian base-64 ASCII strings (of length zero to six). If the
string used as argument for \textbf{a64l}() has length greater than six,
only the first six bytes are used. If the type \emph{long} has more than
32 bits, then \textbf{l64a}() uses only the low order 32 bits of
\emph{value}, and \textbf{a64l}() sign-extends its 32-bit result.

The 64 digits in the base-64 system are:

\begin{verbatim}

'.' represents a 0
'/' represents a 1
0-9 represent  2-11
A-Z represent 12-37
a-z represent 38-63
\end{verbatim}

So 123 = 59*64\^{}0 + 1*64\^{}1 = ``v/''.

\hyperdef{}{ATTRIBUTES}{\section{\hyperref[ATTRIBUTES]{ATTRIBUTES}}\label{ATTRIBUTES}}

\hyperdef{}{Multithreadingux5fux28seeux5fpthreadsux287ux29ux29}{\subsection{\hyperref[Multithreadingux5fux28seeux5fpthreadsux287ux29ux29]{Multithreading
(see
pthreads(7))}}\label{Multithreadingux5fux28seeux5fpthreadsux287ux29ux29}}

The \textbf{l64a}() function is not thread-safe.

The \textbf{a64l}() function is thread-safe.

\hyperdef{}{CONFORMINGux5fTO}{\section{\hyperref[CONFORMINGux5fTO]{CONFORMING
TO}}\label{CONFORMINGux5fTO}}

POSIX.1-2001.

\hyperdef{}{NOTES}{\section{\hyperref[NOTES]{NOTES}}\label{NOTES}}

The value returned by \textbf{l64a}() may be a pointer to a static
buffer, possibly overwritten by later calls.

The behavior of \textbf{l64a}() is undefined when \emph{value} is
negative. If \emph{value} is zero, it returns an empty string.

These functions are broken in glibc before 2.2.5 (puts most significant
digit first).

This is not the encoding used by \textbf{uuencode}(1).

\hyperdef{}{SEEux5fALSO}{\section{\hyperref[SEEux5fALSO]{SEE
ALSO}}\label{SEEux5fALSO}}

\textbf{uuencode}(1), \textbf{strtoul}(3)

\hyperdef{}{COLOPHON}{\section{\hyperref[COLOPHON]{COLOPHON}}\label{COLOPHON}}

This page is part of release 3.54 of the Linux \emph{man-pages} project.
A description of the project, and information about reporting bugs, can
be found at http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/.

\begin{longtable}[c]{@{}ll@{}}
\toprule\addlinespace
2013-06-21 &
\\\addlinespace
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT**

As, no answer is fitted perfectly for the requirement, I made a change in my question. The change also give me the same result, but in different way.

Mainly, I want to link all bold text with the title of same word.
e.g. Where I get `\textbf{malloc}` I want to make a link with `\title{MALLOC(3)}` and `\textbf{a64l}` to `\title{A64L(3)}`.

Now, I make a file `index` that contains the title word.
File **index**

```
MALLOC(3)
A64L(3)
```

or

```
 MALLOC
 A64L
```

or

```
 malloc
 a64l
```

I guess using the `index` file modifying the main file is easier than previous way.
**pseudo code**

```
while read word
do
l_word=${word,,}
echo $l_word
sed -e 's/\\title{$word\(3\)}/\\title{\\hypertarget{$word}{$word\(3\)}}/' -e 's/\\textbf{$l_word}/\\textbf{\\hyperlink{$word}{$l_word}}/' inputfile > output.tex
done < index
```

[There some mistakes in this code, that can't be detected by me]

Comment: Considering there is a [Vim-latex suite](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vim-latex), you might get better answers on the Tex stack exchange.  The answers here are likely to be general text processing answers, but I wouldn't be surprised if there is a macro or a keybinding to do exactly what you want already built into the Vim-latex suite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
while read word
do
l_word=${word,,}
sed -e s/\\\\title{$word\(3\)}/\\\\title{\\\\hypertarget{$word}{$word\(3\)}}/g -e s/\\\\textbf{$l_word}/\\\\textbf{\\\\hyperlink{$word}{$l_word}}/g inputfile > output.tex
done < index
```

Although, this works, it can be done without the index file that's regex I can't make.

Comment: This repeats the parenthesized value, e.g. "{a64l(3)}{A64L(3)}}" rather than outputting "{a64l}{A64L(3)}".

Comment: @DennisWilliamson Yes. For, this I didn't mark that as correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

I guess below one works kindly check and update . As tested for some data its worked for me

```
sed "/title/s/{.*/{\hypertarget{&&/g" filename | sed -e "/title/s/A64/a64/1" -e "/title/s/MALLOC/malloc/1" | sed "/textbf/s/{.*}/{\hyperlink&&/g"| sed "s/{\{2\}/{/1"  | sed "s/(3)//1"
```

Comment: please, describe what you have done. see also my comment on @Jesse_b's answer. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/413562/replacing-different-string-with-different-new-string-that-follows-a-pattern#comment741939_413588

Comment: `sed "/textbf/s/{.*}/{\\\hyperlink&&}/g" filename` and `sed "/title/s/{.*/{\\\hypertarget&&}/g" filename` solves 80% of my question. Just I need to make small letter of first word of first command. That means I need something like `sed "/textbf/s/{.*}/{\\\hyperlink\cap(&)&}/g" filename`

Comment: `sed "/title/s/{.*/{\\\hypertarget\L&\U&}/g" delete` done this.

Comment: But I want to exclude section part(e.g.`(3)`) in link. I need `\title{\hypertarget{malloc}{MALLOC}(3)}`

Comment: if you want (3) with blank use mentioned command sed "s/(3)//g"

Comment: this make all `(3)` as blank.